# two level authentication test

Tags: rest, postman, hp-uft

the app we have has two levels of authentication. First it authorizes user with a Basic token. This authentication generates bearer token (session specific). The user can use this bearer token to various transactions in the app.

Flows:

1. user authentication at auth.xxxx.com  with Basic token
2. user then redirected to api.xxx.com to do various transactions - uses bearer token generated from 1

I am not understanding how I could use basic / bearer session token any tools available, I have tried it in PostMan and HP's UFT.

The situation aptly described here from a developer standpoint: [How to implement two level authentication in a RESTful API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20127743/how-to-implement-two-level-authentication-in-a-restful-api)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to capture the passKey using Json Extractor and then use RegEx extractor to get bearer token. NO programming was required